# Android: adb pull error, myfile.txt does not exist

Tags: android, adb

I'm developing an app that does some heavy html parsing.  I want to make sure that the html and css have been properly formatted (I have strong reason to believe they are not).  using logcat is not particularly helpuful since there is a great deal of text to sift through.  So I thought why not write it to a file and then read that file (with my eyes) to see if it looks write. I believe adb pull is the command that will pull the file off of my emulator and onto my desktop.  Windows 7 is my development operating system.  When I use adb pull 'myfile.txt' I get an error that says my file doesn't exist. Here's the java function I wrote to create the text file:

```
private void cbdLog(String s){
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    if(root.canWrite()){

        try {
            File cbdLog = new File(root, "myfile.txt");
            FileWriter logWriter = new FileWriter(cbdLog);
            BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(logWriter);
            out.write(s);
            out.close();
            Log.d("YO!", "Log file has been written");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    else{
        Log.d("YO!", "Loggin failed");
    }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the full command you used?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file will probably be located on /sdcard/myfile.txt since you are storing it on the root of the external storage (which is the sdcard I assume). Try pulling your file from there:

```
adb pull /sdcard/myfile.txt .
```

Comment: i figured as much a while back but this was the solution to my problem

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to pull a file from a local app dir, you'll get permission error, since only the app has permission for its own files

This will solve the issue:

```
> adb shell
shell $ run-as com.contapps.android
shell $ chmod 666 databases/file
shell $ exit                                               ## exit out of 'run-as'
shell $ cp /data/data/package.name/databases/file /sdcard/
shell $ run-as com.contapps.android
shell $ chmod 600 databases/file
> adb pull /sdcard/file .
```

Comment: I found the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21151598/1613961) is similar to yours, but a little quicker.

Answer (score 1):

Since 4.4 there is no way to copy file to the sdcard from run-as
so now I change file permition to 666 with 
chmod 666 file_name

and use
adb pull with full path to the file

since 5.0 pull for such files doesn't work.

And I moved to adb shell cat path_to_file_on_android_fs > path_on_local_fs

that still works for me :)

Answer (score 0):

Try `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();`.

Answer (score 0):

You can drag&drop files from the emulator by going into the DDMS perspective and selecting the file view.  Your file should be in there somewhere.