# Browse SQLite database from Android Studio

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio, ddms, stetho

I would like to know is there any SQLite plugin for Android Studio which will allow user to browse the created database?

Answer (score 66):

**UPDATE July 2020**

With **Android Studio 4.1** (Canary 6 and higher), you can inspect, query, and modify your app's databases using the new **Database Inspector**.

You can find the [official doc here](https://developer.android.com/studio/preview/features#database-inspector).

---

Currently there isn't an official plugin for DB Inspection in your apps.

- You can use the  **DDMS** : Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor as described in @Subhalaxmi's answer
- There is a **beta plugin** provided by **idescout** that you can try [here](http://www.idescout.com/).
- There is the **Stetho** tool (open source and free) provided by Facebook

I suggest you using the [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/) open-sourced tool provided by Facebook. It is simple to implement and very powerful.

Just add the dependencies in your `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
    // Stetho core
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'       

    //Optional network helper
    compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho-okhttp:1.3.1'       
}
```

Then just initialize the tool in your Application class:

```
Stetho.initialize(Stetho.newInitializerBuilder(this)
        .enableDumpapp(Stetho.defaultDumperPluginsProvider(this))
        .enableWebKitInspector(Stetho.defaultInspectorModulesProvider(this))
        .build());
```

Finally just open **Chrome** on your pc and navigare in *chrome://inspect*.

Here you can display the database in the app (with read/write capabilities), and you can run queries.

[image]

You can find more info about Stetho here:

- http://gmariotti.blogspot.it/2015/07/a-first-glance-at-stetho-tool.html
- http://facebook.github.io/stetho/

Comment: Thanks for the tip, very useful tool.

Comment: The code as given above will just build, but not use, a Stetho initializer. To actually perform initialization, call Stetho.initialize(initializer); where "initializer" is what the call to build() returns.

Comment: @Dabbler +1 - I edited the answer as I too didn't realise I hadn't initialised Stetho yet - took me a little while to figure out why it wasn't working ;-)

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks a lot sir !

Comment: stetho does not work anymore from Chrome 72+

Comment: @gabiteris Yes. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/634)

Answer (score 13):

Install [Sqlite](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Open DDMS : `Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor`

Click on your device on the left.

You should see your application:

Go to `File Explorer`(one of the tabs on the right), go to `/data/data/databases` and select your application `package`

Ex: check  image

[image]

Select the database by just clicking on it.

Go to the top right corner of the Android Device Monitor window.

Click on the `pull a file from the device` button:

[image]

A window will open asking you where you want to save your database file.Save it anywhere you want on your PC.

Now, open the SQLiteBrowser you installed. Click on `open database`, navigate to the location you saved the database file, and open.You can now view the contents of your database.

Comment: I am unable to expand the data folder in the File Explorer, any idea why?

Answer (score 8):

I'm using [TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse](https://github.com/TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse) for instant browsing inside `Android Device Monitor`. I found it the fastest and most practical way.

Just download the jar from the [releases](https://github.com/TKlerx/android-sqlite-browser-for-eclipse/releases) page and place it in the `[android-sdk-folder]/tools/lib/monitor-x86_64/plugins`.

Afterwards, just browse any database file inside the `File Explorer` and click the blue-ish icon shown in the picture:

[image]

Enjoy !

Comment: I was exactly looking for this.

Answer (score 2):

There is no such feature or plugin for Android Studio at least now.

Check out [stetho](https://github.com/facebook/stetho) - one of features of this library is to provide a bridge to view your device database contents directly from Chrome Developer Tools in desktop Chrome browser.

Answer (score 2):

You should go to Tools>Android>Android device monitor 
it would then launch the android device monitor 
Then you should navigate to the file explorer in the Android device monitor and then navigate to the database where you have saved it in the device and then use the option pull a file from a device. and save the database file where ever  you want and if you want to open and view the data in it use the following link

[SqLiteBrowser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/)

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, currently there is no plugin available to browse SQLite database directly from the Android Studio.
You can extract your database file from "File Explorer".

You can find "File Explorer" from here.

> Tools > Android > Android Device Monitor

Answer (score 1):

You can browse your database using [Firefox Extension](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/).

Visit [Android Studio Plugins](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/?androidstudio) for android-studio related plugins.