# Android: Show SQLite on Mac

Tags: android, macos, sqlite, android-studio, android-sqlite

I'm doing some `Android` programming on a `Mac` in `Android Studio`.
I can't seem to find my database in the terminal.

I'm using `Android Studio` and I think I found the folder where I should do the commands: `/library/Android/sdk/platform-tools/sqlite3.`

Maybe someone could give a quick walkthrough?

Comment: No need of any application, mozilla has and add-on for SQLite - https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/

Comment: do you need walkthrough on how to create a database? or you want to be able to look at your db on device?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138442/browse-sqlite-database-from-android-studio/31465301#31465301

Answer (score 0):

run sqlite3 command on your device

try this on a emulator or rooted device

> adb shell -- logged into the device

/data/data/com.me.myapp/databases/mydb.db // location of sqlite file for your app

> sqlite3 /data/data/com.me.myapp/databases/mydb.db

....
run sql commands

....

> .exit

Alternatively , you can set up stetho library for your project to view the sqlite file on chrome dev tools https://code.facebook.com/posts/393927910787513/stetho-a-new-debugging-platform-for-android/