# Is there any SqlLite extension for Android Studio?

Tags: mysql, sqlite, android-studio, plugins

Checked some forums for sql extensions in Android studio but posts are older, does someone know if there is new extension or plugin for Android Studio to manage databases?

Comment: As far as I know, there is still no official plugin for database inspection, but check  [this answers](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29138442/browse-sqlite-database-from-android-studio) for 3rd party tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is [one](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/CONTEST/Database+Navigator):

Database Navigator

> Database development, scripting and navigation tool This product adds
>   extensive database development and maintenance capabilities to the
>   IntelliJ IDEA development environment and related products. Along with
>   a qualified and IDE-compliant SQL and PL/SQL editor, it provides
>   advanced database connection management, script execution support,
>   database objects browsing, data and code editor, support for database
>   compiler operations, method execution and debugging, database objects
>   factory, as well as various navigation capabilities between all its
>   components. See features overview on the support page.  Supported
>   Databases: Oracle MySQL SQLite PostgreSQL

Checked it with Android Studio 2.3.3 - configured .db sqlite file in it, checked queries - works well so far, but I notices some oddies: lags when viewing table schema/columns and finally they are not showed for me.

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)