# I cant see my database in Android Studio File Manager

Tags: android, sqlitemanager

I have been following a tutorial line by line, and I cant seem to find my database in the /data/data/com.package.www/databases/.
It is filled with con folders.
There are no errors whatsoever while debugging.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need root on device and do some command in terminal. See detail ([How do I view the SQLite database on an Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android))
Without root you see empty folder.

Another way (without roots: [How to access data/data folder in Android device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13006315/how-to-access-data-data-folder-in-android-device))

Sory for my bad english

Comment: I am talking about when I use the android studio device manager.

Comment: I would add an image but I am not able to