# how to pull database from ddms when device is connected

Tags: android

how can i pull database file from DDMS,  when device is connected? I know how to pull while running in android emulator.  But i want to pull it when device is connected? Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the sqlite database in device android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android)

Comment: You will need root access on device to do it. is your device rooted?

Answer (score 0):

I think i understand your questions, you are asking that the path to grab database from android device.

we can't get some devices database, so i think possible solution is to create a backup button in your project to copy database from private folders of app and paste it to SD card. then you can access the database by using sqlite browser.

**Here is the code to copy database :**

```
// method to get backup
    public void BackupDatabase() throws IOException
    {
        try {
                File sd = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"");//getBaseContext().getFilesDir();
                File data = Environment.getDataDirectory();

                if(sd == null || !sd.canWrite() ){
                    sd = getBaseContext().getFilesDir();
                }
            if (sd.canWrite())
            {
                String currentDBPath = "/data/your.package.name/databases/YourDatabaseName";
                File temp = new File(sd, "BackupFolderInSDCard");
                if(!temp.exists())
                    temp.mkdirs();

                File backupDB = new File(temp,"backup.db");
                File currentDB = new File(data, currentDBPath);

                if (currentDB.exists()) 
                {
                    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(currentDB);
                    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis,1024);

                    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(backupDB);
                    BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(fos, 1024);

                    byte arr[] = new byte[1024];
                    int ch;
                    while( (ch = bis.read(arr)) != -1 )
                    {
                        bos.write(arr, 0, ch);
                    }

                    bos.close(); fos.close();
                    bis.close(); fis.close();
//                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "File Saved To\n"+ backupDB.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Database Stored in SD Card", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
                else
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Database Doesn't Exist"+ backupDB.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
```