# sqlite in the xamarin android player

Tags: xamarin

I have clicked on `Tools -> Android -> Android Device Monitor` in `VS 2015` and got the following error, but my xamarin android player works fine.

[image]

Is there a way to access to local database (sqlite) in the xamarin android player simulator not on the physical device?

**Update**:

I am using adb and getting the following error

[image]

Comment: The error msg is pretty clear, isn't it?

Comment: It is, java is 32 bit installed for xamarin android player. If I removed that folder then it will direct to 64 bit installation, but then xamarin player wont work.

Comment: What type of access do you need to the file? Do you need to copy it from the emulator? To the emulator? Or?

Comment: I just need to access and open my sqlite file with db visualizer tool

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to view the sqlite database in device android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-to-view-the-sqlite-database-in-device-android)

Comment: I added a dup link, using Android's `adb` is the way to copy files to/from your device/emulator to your local pc filesystem

Comment: I am not using Android Studio, I am using Visual Studio

Comment: FYI: `adb` is **the** console interface to your device, it is used by all toolsets, include Visual Studio/Xamarin for deploying apks, frameworks, installing, uninstalling, logcat output...

Comment: I am trying to access on the simulator, not in the device at the moment. I have run the command on adb and got the following error : `no devices found`

Comment: Is your emulator currently running? If so try doing a `adb devices` to get the current list of devices that are running/connected/available (this is same method Xamarin uses to see which devices it can deploy to).

Comment: If I only type `adb devices`, I could able to see a single device attched. But when I type the command `adb -d shell "run-as com.SM.Android ls /data/data/com.SM.Android/databases/"` I am getting no devices found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Failed to load the JNI shared library "C:/XXXXX/jvm.dll"`.

This is a sign of a mixed 32/64 Java bit Java install **and/or** the wrong version is installed.

**Xamarin on Windows requires a Windows x86 version of v1.7**

> It is essential to install the 32-bit version of the Java JDK even if you're using 64-bit Windows. It is also important that v1.7 of the Java JDK is installed (although it is fine to have 1.8 or newer installed at the same time).

So I would start by installing Java `v1.7`, since the error is pointing to `v1.6` and retrying to open the `Android Device Monitor`.

> Installing the Java SDK (JDK)
>
> The JDK can be downloaded from any browser by visiting Oracle’s [website](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html) and browsing to the section with the heading Java SE Development Kit 7u79

Ref: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/getting_started/installation/windows/manual_installation/#Installing_the_Java_SDK_JDK

Comment: If I only type `adb devices`, I could able to see a single device attached. But when I type the command `adb -d shell "run-as com.SM.Android ls /data/data/com.SM.Android/databases/"` I am getting `no devices found`

Comment: @hotspring Try `adb connect {device:port}` first.. It should auto connect if only one device is available, otherwise you have to specify the device host:port for the command to be executed against.

Comment: I have tried and got the following error: `unable to connect to {10.71.34.101:55555 }cannot resolve host and port, no such host is known`

Comment: @hotspring Is it "55555" or "5555"? Normal they start at 5555 (4 digits)

Comment: sorry I have mistyped, only four digits. I have tried and got the following error: `unable to connect to {10.71.34.101:5555 }cannot resolve host and port, no such host is known`

Comment: @hostspring Are you including the braces? that is a substitution indictor, do not include those... see http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html for details

Comment: Please see my updated question included a screen shot.

Comment: ok, I have removed the braces and it says it is already connected, it is good indication :-) Now how could I able to access to sqlite file? I have checked my manifest is to make sure, my application is called `schedulingmonitor` I have tried the following `adb -d shell "run-as com.schedulingmonitor ls /data/data/com.schedulingmonitor/databases/"` but it gives me no devices found error

Comment: I have posted the answer. Thanks for your effort.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**

I run `tools->android-> android adb command prompt` in visual studio

I have followed the followings to access the database

step1. >`adb shell`

step2. >`cd data/data`

step3. >`ls -l|grep "com.xxxx"`

step4. >`cd "com.xxxx"`

Then I used the following to copy sql file to my workstation

```
adb shell "run-as com.xxxx chmod 666 /data/data/com.xxxx/files"
adb pull /data/data/com.xxxx/files/xx.sql
adb shell "run-as com.xxxx chmod 600 /data/data/com.xxxx/files"
```

Then I have downloaded [sqlite browser](http://sqlitebrowser.org/) to open the file and see the tables.

**Solution 2:**

Alternatively, you can go to following directory and double click the exe file

```
C:\Users\XXXXX\AppData\Local\Android\ANDROI~1\tools\lib\monitor-x86_64\monitor.exe
```