# Stetho, not seen inspect link

Tags: android, database, stetho

[image]

As you see in the picture, inspect link is not seen. I did steps in this answer:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32173974/5118976
After I run application on the my phone but there is no inspect link. Why does this problem occur? How to solve?

Answer (score 3):

Add

```
compile 'com.facebook.stetho:stetho:1.3.1'
```

in gradle file.

and confirm you added

```
Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this);
```

in application class

Comment: I did steps in the answer. But I added to module.app gradle is it true? or Should I add to project gradle?

Comment: build.gradle(Module:app)

Comment: I was forgot `Stetho.initializeWithDefaults(this)`

Answer (score 1):

I had same issues in android

I refer this line.https://github.com/facebook/stetho/issues/40

This is know issues .

After created the sqlite it does not work u want uninstall the app and install it will work .It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from creating the application class please make sure it's also added to the Manifest file. :)

```
 <application
    android:name=".App" // application class
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
   ...
   ...
 />
```