# How to browse data live in Xamarin.Forms App using a Azure SQLite Database

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-sqlite, azure-mobile-services

I am writing a Xamarin.Forms Android Azure Mobile Apps App and want to take a look into my SQLite database while debugging my app. I am using Offline Sync.

Is there a good tool I can use for that like SQL Server Management Studio for MS SQL Server databases?

thanks,
Eric

Answer (score 0):

Something like http://sqlitebrowser.org/ for instance?  Google is your friend.

Comment: I have no idea how to connect to my phone with that tool to see "live" data. I guess I could only make a dump / snapdhot and download the local db via adb command and open it with that tool. a cumbersome way.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19194576/how-do-i-view-the-sqlite-database-on-an-android-device

Comment: Also: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.xuecs.sqlitemanager&hl=en - have not tried it.

Comment: Thanks Adrian, but all of that is for offline usage. You have to pull the db from the phone. I need some online connection if possible to rhe Sqlite store on the phone for debug puposes. Obviously the Sqlite DB stays opaque ;-) But I will check that playstore app.