# SQLite onUpgrade removing and adding column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite, alter-table

In my Android project I've got a table which I used for a while. Now I want to remove a column 'image_byte' and add a new one 'image_path'. I cannot just rename the column as the app is being used and it needs to remove the text in image_byte so it will not be used anymore.

I implement SQLiteOpenHelper and the following code is in onUpgrade:

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
    //check if upgrade is really needed
    if(newVersion > oldVersion) {
        tableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table1 ( id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT, image_path TEXT)";

        db.execSQL(tableSQL);

        //get all the current tableName table columns
        List<String> columns = getColumns(db, "table1");

        //rename the old table
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO temp_table1;");

        //create the new tableName table
        db.execSQL(tableSQL);

        //merge the old and new columns, keep all the old ones
        columns.retainAll(getColumns(db, "table1"));
        String cols = joinColumnNames(columns, ",");

        //insert the old data in the new table
        db.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM temp_%s", "table1", cols, cols, "table1"));

        //delete the old temp table
        db.execSQL("DROP table 'temp_table1'");
    }
}
```

And the getColumns function:

```
private List<String> getColumns(SQLiteDatabase db, String tableName){
    List<String> ar = null;
    Cursor c = null;
    try{
        c = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + tableName + " limit 1", null);
        if(c != null){
            ar = new ArrayList< >(Arrays.asList(c.getColumnNames()));
        }
    } catch (Exception e){

    } finally {
        if (c != null){
            c.close();
        }
    }
    return ar;
}
```

But when debugging the app, it says that column 'image_byte' does not exist and that it cannot copy the contents from temp_table1 to table1. Which is correct, because it is now 'image_path' and image_byte shouldn't be copied. But why is getColumns returning the old columns? Because when I use Log.d, it shows 'id', 'name', 'image_byte'. Therefore the retainAll function will not drop 'image_byte'. I can't seem to figure out why it still returns image_byte. It's probably stupid and simple but I just don't see it.

Comment: That function executes `tableSQL` two times. This does not make sense.

Comment: @CL. It is not great code, I agree. But since the SQL is "CREATE IF NOT EXISTS" it is there to make sure the table is there before doing the other operations. Used when I add a whole new table to the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe that the issue may well be due to caching in that `columns.retainAll(getColumns(db, "table1"));` appears to retrieve the columns from the original table1.

This is the results from some testing that I have undertaken:-

```
10-15 13:37:19.319 26740-26740/? D/DBINFO: onUpgrade Started.
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/DBINFO: Databse info in onUpgrade after table rename to temp_table1
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/mjt.sqlitedbexamples/databases/imagestore
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = temp_table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE "temp_table1"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,image_byte TEXT)
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.320 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = image_byte ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/DBINFO: Databse info in onUpgrade after creation of new table1.
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/mjt.sqlitedbexamples/databases/imagestore
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = temp_table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE "temp_table1"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,image_byte TEXT)
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = image_byte ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image_path TEXT)
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = image_path ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/ORIG COLUMNS: Orignal Column Info - Column=id Column=name Column=image_byte 
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/NEWTAB COLUMNS: Columns from new table1 - Column=id Column=name Column=image_byte 
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/RETAIN COLUMNS: Columns After Retain - Column=id Column=name Column=image_byte 
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? D/JOINED COLUMNS: id,name,image_byte
10-15 13:37:19.321 26740-26740/? E/SQLiteLog: (1) table table1 has no column named image_byte
10-15 13:37:19.329 26740-26740/? D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
```

The last few lines D/ORIG COLUMNS, D/NEWTAB COLUMNS, D/RETAIN COLUMNS. D/RETAIN COLUMNS indicates that image_byte has been extracted.

Perhaps introducing an intermediate table name and then finally rename that to the original table name may resolve that issue.

Note the SQLITE_CSU output was produced from the utilities mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues).

This is the onUpgrade code useed for testing/producing the above:-

```
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {
        String tableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TBNAME + "(" +
                "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
                "name TEXT," +
                "image_path TEXT" +
                ")";
        if (newversion > oldversion) {
            Log.d("DBINFO","onUpgrade Started.");
            db.execSQL(tableSQL);

            //get all the current tableName table columns
            List<String> columns = getColumns(db, "table1");

            //rename the old table
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE table1 RENAME TO temp_table1;");
            Log.d("DBINFO","Databse info in onUpgrade after table rename to temp_table1");
            CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(db);

            //create the new tableName table
            db.execSQL(tableSQL);
            Log.d("DBINFO","Databse info in onUpgrade after creation of new table1.");
            CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(db);

            //merge the old and new columns, keep all the old ones
            String loginfo = "Orignal Column Info - ";
            for (String s:columns) {
                loginfo = loginfo + "Column=" + s + " ";
            }
            Log.d("ORIG COLUMNS",loginfo);
            loginfo = "Columns from new table1 - ";
            for (String s: getColumns(db, "table1")) {
                loginfo = loginfo + "Column=" + s + " ";
            }
            Log.d("NEWTAB COLUMNS",loginfo);
            columns.retainAll(getColumns(db, "table1"));
            loginfo = "Columns After Retain - ";
            for (String s: columns) {
                loginfo = loginfo + "Column=" + s + " ";
            }
            Log.d("RETAIN COLUMNS",loginfo);
            String cols = joinColumnNames(columns, ",");
            Log.d("JOINED COLUMNS",cols);

            //insert the old data in the new table
            db.execSQL(String.format("INSERT INTO %s (%s) SELECT %s FROM temp_%s", "table1", cols, cols, "table1"));

            //delete the old temp table
            db.execSQL("DROP table 'temp_table1'");
            Log.d("DBINFO","Databse info in onUpgrade after DELETING temp_table1.");
        }
```

---

#### Working example :-

In this example the data is extracted from the original table into a Cursor, the new table is created with a different name, this new table is loaded with the data then the old table is dropped and finally the new table is renamed.

This may be a slightly more complicated as it maintains the **id**, it's only 1 line though :-

```
cv.put("id",Long.toString(olddata.getLong(olddata.getColumnIndex("id"))));
```

Note! lines commenetd with `//<<<<<` are purely for logging the activity. Although `olddata.moveToPosition(-1); //<<<<<` is needed if the oldata Cursor is read/traversed (i.e. to return the position to before the first row).

```
@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldversion, int newversion) {

    String temptableSQL = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS temp_" + TBNAME + "(" +
            "id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, " +
            "name TEXT," +
            "image_path TEXT" +
            ")";
    if (newversion > oldversion) {
        Log.d("DBINFO","onUpgrade Started.");
        db.execSQL(temptableSQL);

        Cursor olddata = db.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null);
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logCursorData(olddata); //<<<<
        olddata.moveToPosition(-1); //<<<<<

        //db.execSQL(tableSQL);
        Log.d("DBINFO","Databse info in onUpgrade after creation of new table1.");
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(db); //<<<<<
        Log.d("DBCOPYDATA",
                "Copying data from OLD Data. # rows = " +  
                        Integer.toString(olddata.getCount())
        ); //<<<<<
        while (olddata.moveToNext()) {
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            Log.d("DBCOPYDATA","ROW " + Integer.toString(olddata.getPosition()) +
                    "\n\tID=" + Long.toString(olddata.getLong(olddata.getColumnIndex("id"))) +
                    "\n\tNAME=" + olddata.getString(olddata.getColumnIndex("name")) +
                    "\n\tIMG =" + olddata.getString(olddata.getColumnIndex("image_byte"))
            ); //<<<<<
            cv.put("id",Long.toString(olddata.getLong(olddata.getColumnIndex("id"))));
            cv.put("name",olddata.getString(olddata.getColumnIndex("name")));
            cv.put("image_path",olddata.getString(olddata.getColumnIndex("image_byte")));

            Long id = db.insert("temp_" + TBNAME,null,cv);
            Log.d("DBCOPYDATA","INSERTED ID=" + Long.toString(id)); //<<<<<

        }
        olddata.close();
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TBNAME);
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE temp_" + TBNAME + " RENAME TO " + TBNAME);

        Cursor csr = db.query(TBNAME,null,null,null,null,null,null); //<<<<<
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(db); //<<<<<
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logCursorData(csr); //<<<<<
        csr.close(); //<<<<<
    }
}
```

Output from a successful test :-

```
10-15 17:54:41.618 16960-16960/? D/DBINFO: onUpgrade Started.
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: logCursorData Cursor has 3 rows with 3 columns.
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 1 offset=0
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 1 value as long is 1 value as double is 1.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 2 offset=1
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 2 value as long is 2 value as double is 2.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image002 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 3 offset=2
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 3 value as long is 3 value as double is 3.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image003 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/DBINFO: Databse info in onUpgrade after creation of new table1.
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/mjt.sqlitedbexamples/databases/imagestore
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
10-15 17:54:41.619 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,name TEXT,image_byte TEXT)
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = image_byte ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = temp_table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE temp_table1(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image_path TEXT)
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = temp_table1 ColumnName = image_path ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: Copying data from OLD Data. # rows = 3
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: ROW 0
                                                ID=1
                                                NAME=Test001
                                                IMG =mypath/mypath/images/image001
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: INSERTED ID=1
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: ROW 1
                                                ID=2
                                                NAME=Test001
                                                IMG =mypath/mypath/images/image002
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: INSERTED ID=2
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: ROW 2
                                                ID=3
                                                NAME=Test001
                                                IMG =mypath/mypath/images/image003
10-15 17:54:41.620 16960-16960/? D/DBCOPYDATA: INSERTED ID=3
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/mjt.sqlitedbexamples/databases/imagestore
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = table1 Created Using = CREATE TABLE "table1"(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT,image_path TEXT)
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = table1 ColumnName = image_path ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: logCursorData Cursor has 3 rows with 3 columns.
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 1 offset=0
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 1 value as long is 1 value as double is 1.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 2 offset=1
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 2 value as long is 2 value as double is 2.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image002 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
10-15 17:54:41.621 16960-16960/? D/SQLITE_CSU: Information for row 3 offset=2
                                                For Column id Type is INTEGER value as String is 3 value as long is 3 value as double is 3.0
                                                For Column name Type is STRING value as String is Test001 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
                                                For Column image_byte Type is STRING value as String is mypath/mypath/images/image003 value as long is 0 value as double is 0.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this seems to be the solution and you put in a lot of time. Great help! It's a shame SQLite messes up the caching.

Comment: @TruffelNL Another solution would be to use `PRAGMA table_info` to get the column names (as used in the utils I used and linked to). From the first log, this got image_path from table1.