# Since when does sqlite's persist journal mode become the default journal mode in Android?

Tags: android, sqlite, sqlite-journal-mode

Since when does sqlite's persist journal mode become the default journal mode in Android?

I know that the journal mode have changed in Android version 4.1.1 (API 16). But it is not accurate. Because the release notes do not contain this information. I do not know if i can find in release note. If you know someone who knows exactly when SQLite journal mode was changed in Android, plz let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think journal_mode is PERSIST by default rather that DELETE is the default. However, that is only a) according to the SQLIte documentation and b) checking a few emulated devices and one real device:-

- real device HTC Android 6.0.1
- GenyMotion device 6.0.0
- GenyMotion device 5.1.0

I believe vendors may have the ability to alter various factors that would probably make an actual date or version unreliable anyway.

Screen Shots from the GenyMotion devices (just so happens I'm playing around with something that provides this information) :-

[image]

[image]

Comment: Once upon a time, HTC thought it would be a good idea to change the default journal mode to WAL. [Many apps blew up](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4718934/sqlite-issues-with-htc-desire-hd).

Comment: @CL should now be safe with an HTC then, assuming they learnt from their mistake :)