# Database update is unsuccessful

Tags: java, android, android-sqlite

I am pretty new to android application development. In my app ,I am trying to add money to the wallet which is unsuccessful. The logcat does not show any error in the execution.

Here i am posting myDbAdapter.java(database), add_amount.java and activity_add_amount.xml.

The add_amount.java is as follows:

```
public class Add_Amount extends AppCompatActivity {
    TextView amount;
    String total;
    TextView up;
    private no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter mydb;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_add__amount);
        up=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView_wallet);
        amount=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.editText_amount);
        String Amount=(String)amount.getText().toString();
        mydb = new no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter(this);
        Cursor rs = mydb.getData(1);
        rs.moveToFirst();
        String wall=rs.getString(rs.getColumnIndex(no.nordicsemi.android.nrftoolbox.myDbAdapter.CONTACTS_COLUMN_WALLET));
        total=Amount+wall;

    }
    public void addamt(View v){
        boolean b=mydb.updateWallet(total,1);
        if(b==true)
            message(getApplicationContext(),"updated");
        else
            message(getApplicationContext(),"not updated");
    }
}
```

The updateWallet function in myDbAdapter.java is as follows:

```
    public boolean updateWallet(String amount,Integer id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("wallet",amount);
        db.update("contacts",contentValues,"id = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(id)});
        return true;
    }
}
```

When I click the button (Add amount) after entering any amount , toast message "updated" is displayed. But it is not getting updated.

Where is the possible error ?

Comment: Everytime you are updating wallet of that person whose id is 1

Comment: Think about shortening the code by removing the parts that might not have anything to do with your problem. This will result in more people reading the question as they don't need to look for the code parts that are crucial.

Comment: Yes. My intention here is to test the app for id=1 entry. @AbhishekSingh

Comment: Sure. Updated the code by shortening and including only useful data. Thanks a lot. @DawidZbiński

Comment: @VINNYKINGER Solved this yet?

Comment: Not yet.Still trying @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: https://www.androidhive.info/2011/11/android-sqlite-database-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

**`new String[] { Integer.toString(1)}`** . As a result, row updated **`WHERE ID=1`**.

You should pass **`DYNAMIC`** value instead of ***static*** **`1`**.
You can pass **`email`**.

```
public boolean updateWallet(String amount,final int _id)
    {
        SQLiteDatabase db=this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues=new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put("wallet",amount);
        db.update("contacts",contentValues,"id = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(_id)});
        return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as there are no SQL issues (e.g. column/table not found i.e. exceptions raised) then irrespective of whether or not an update occurred true will be returned by the code you currently have.

However, just because the `update` doesn't fail with an exception (e.g. column/table name not found), it doesn't mean that updates were made.

*For example; if you passed an number for an **id** that doesn't exist the update will not issue an exception, rather nothing will be updated as there is no row to update.*

As the [**`update`**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#update%28java.lang.String,%20android.content.ContentValues,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String[]%29) method returns the number of updated rows as an int, you could use this by replacing :-

```
    db.update("contacts",contentValues,"id = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(id)});
    return true;
```

with something along the lines of :-

```
    return (db.update("contacts",contentValues,"id = ? ",new String[] { Integer.toString(_id)}) > 0);
```

Doing so will split your issue into two :-

- If **0** is returned and the Toast is **`not updated`**; then for some reason the update didn't happen (e.g. no row with the specified id exists).
- If **> 0** is returned and the Toast displays **`updated`**; then the issue is likely to do with whatever method you are using to determine that no rows appear to have been updated.

*Perhaps you could make use of the methods [found here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues) that can be used to display database/table information to the Log.*

Comment: Toast displayed "updated ". Now from the link mentioned above, where do need to insert those codes?? @MikeT

Comment: @VINNYKINGER use `getAllRowsfromTable` to create Cursor for `logCursorData` method,  use them both before and after the update in `updateWallet` method (or elsewhere if need be).

Comment: when i am inserting that code its displaying error near "public static Cursor getAllRowsfromTable " saying :inner class cannot have static declaration. .

Comment: You need to create a new Java Class file called `CommonSQLiteUtilities.java`, then copy  the code from the link into that file. You can then use `Cursor csr = CommonSQLiteUtilities.getAllRowsFromTable(db,"contacts",true,null); followed by CommonSQLiteUtilities.LogCursorData(csr);