# List size return 0 from sqlite query

Tags: android, mysql, sqlite, android-cursor

I tried to query a list of premise by joining three tables. However, my list return empty when I added **WHERE**. I tried to log everything.. it seem that without it, I was able to get a list of premise... but it's wrong. I tried running the query on **DB Browser for sqlite**, it manage to run and return the right list. Please help me.

this is my query code..

```
public List<TXN_Premise> getTxnTableData(String tableName, String columnName) {

        ArrayList<TXN_Premise> itemList = new ArrayList<>();
        String selectQuery = "SELECT "
                + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REF + ", "
                + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + ", "
                + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_ADDRESS + ", "
                + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_CATEGORY_ID + " AS " + Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_ID +", "
                + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_ID + " AS " + Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_ID + ", "
                + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REG_NO + ", "
                + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REG_DATE + ", "
                + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " AS premiseCategoryDescription, "
                + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_DESCRIPTION + " AS premiseCategoryMasterDescription "

                + " FROM " + tableName

                + " LEFT JOIN " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + " ON " +
                Constants.TXN_PREMISE_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_ID + " = " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_CODE

                + " LEFT JOIN " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + " ON " +
                Constants.TXN_PREMISE_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_ID + " = " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_CODE

//              + " WHERE " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_LANG + " = 'MYS'"
//              + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_LANG + " = 'MYS' AND "
//              + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-' AND " + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-TIADA-'"

                + " ORDER BY " + columnName + " ASC LIMIT 3";

        Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: " + selectQuery);

        try {
            open();
            //make sure the database is not empty
            if (sqLiteDatabase != null) {
                //get a cursor for all state in the database
                Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

                Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: cursor " + cursor.toString());

                Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: outside");

                if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
                        TXN_Premise premiseColumn = new TXN_Premise();
//                      premiseColumn.setPremiseId(cursor.getString(0));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseRef(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REF)));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME)));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseAddress(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_ADDRESS)));
                        premiseColumn.setFk_premiseCategoryId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_ID)));
                        premiseColumn.setFk_premiseCategoryMasterId(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_FK_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_ID)));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseRegNo(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REG_NO)));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseRegDate(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_REG_DATE)));


                        //  todo: temp premise category description
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseCategoryName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("premiseCategoryDescription")));
                        premiseColumn.setPremiseCategoryMasterName(cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("premiseCategoryMasterDescription")));

                        Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: premiseName " + cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME)));

                        //add premiseColumn in the cursor
                        itemList.add(premiseColumn);
                        cursor.moveToNext();
                    }
                }
                cursor.close();
            }
            close();

        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: itemlist " + itemList.size() );

        return itemList;
    }
```

Comment: Are you getting data from cursor...

Comment: Different query, or different data.

Comment: I'm passing the cursor data to an array..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's impossible to recreate the issue and thus determine the problem as the WHERE clause is reliant upon the underlying data.

As such you need to follow simple problem determination.

As you indicate that it works without the WHERE clause then

- 1) Remove the WHERE clause and run.

  - 1a) If you now retrieve rows then progressively build the WHERE clause condition by condition, that would highlight the issue.
  - 1b) If after removing the WHERE clause the issue of no rows remains then progressively build the entire SQL starting with `String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + tableName;`, checking that the results are as expected.

I would recommend changing

```
    Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: cursor " + cursor.toString());
```

To

```
    Log.d("test", "getTxnTableData: cursor " + cursor.getCount());
```

This will then show the number of rows in the Cursor.

Additionally you could take advantage of [the utillities here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)

---

## Edit

Looking at this more closely, there appears to be some issues with the WHERE clause:-

For simplification, the following resolutions will be made, wherever :-

- `Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE` appears it will be replaced with **`rpc`**
- `Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE` appears it will be replaced with **`mrpc`**
- `Constants.COLUMN_LANG` appears, it will be replaced with **`lang`**
- `Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME` appears, it will be replaced with **`name`**

so :-

```
" WHERE " + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_LANG + " = 'MYS'"
              + Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." + Constants.COLUMN_LANG + " = 'MYS' AND "
              + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-' AND " + Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-TIADA-'"
```

becomes (**`????(n)`** being used to indicate an issue, where n identifies the specific issue, noting that it is not part of the SQL) :-

`" WHERE rpc.lang = 'MYS'` **`????(1)`** `mrpc.lang = 'MYS' AND  name <> '-' AND name <> '-TIADA-'` **`????(2)`**

- Issue 1 **`????(1)`** there is no condition between the two checks e.g. perhaps it should be `WHERE rpc.lang = 'MYS'` **`AND`** `mrpc.lang = 'MYS' .......`

  - This may produce an error along the lines of
  - `.....
    [ near "?????????": syntax error ]
    Exception Name: NS_ERROR_FAILURE
    Exception Message: Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 (NS_ERROR_FAILURE)`
- Issue 2 **`????(2)`** This pair of condition will **NEVER** be met **name** can only be either **-** or *-TIADA-* **NEVER both**. Perhaps you meant **`OR`** in which case I'd enclose them in parenthesises.

So perhaps the code could be :-

```
" WHERE " + 
    Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_TABLE + "." + 
        Constants.COLUMN_LANG + 
        " = 'MYS'" + 
" AND " + 
    Constants.REF_PREMISE_CATEGORY_MASTER_TABLE + "." +
        Constants.COLUMN_LANG + " = 'MYS' " + 
" AND (" +
            Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-' " + 
            "  OR " + 
            Constants.COLUMN_PREMISE_NAME + " <> '-TIADA-'" + 
")"
```

Comment: I'm retrieving rows when I removed the WHERE clause... but even when I added 1 condition... it failed.. i tried changing it to another condition but it still fails

Comment: @hibikiryou please edit your question and include the stack trace from the log to show what error(s) you are getting (if more than one then include the WHERE clause(s)).