# Android Studio: Database Access Issue when clicking the list view

Tags: java, android, sqlite

In the Logicat i am getting and error i have already created my table in the database using navicat

[image]

> **Process: sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection, PID: 23888 java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection/sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Activity.BccListActivity}:
>   android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: bcc (code 1):
>   , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bcc
>                                                                                                  #################################################################
>                                                                                                  Error Code : 1 (SQLITE_ERROR)
>                                                                                                  Caused By : SQL(query) error or missing database.
>                                                                                                     (no such table: bcc (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM bcc)**

Below is the code

```
package sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Databse;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Constant;
import sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Model.Form;
import sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Model.Bcc;
import sspldatacollection.rt.mils.sspldatacollection.Model.User;



public class DatabaseAccess {
private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
private SQLiteDatabase database;
private static DatabaseAccess instance;

/**
 * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
 *
 * @param context
 */
private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
    this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);

}

/**
 * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
 *
 * @param context the Context
 * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
 */
public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
    }
    return instance;
}

/**
 * Open the database connection.
 */
public SQLiteDatabase open() {
    this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this.database;
}

/**
 * Close the database connection.
 */
public void close() {
    if (database != null) {
        this.database.close();
    }
}






/**
 * Read all quotes from the database.
 *
 * @return a List of quotes
 */
public List<User> getUsers() {
    List<User> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM user", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        User u=new User(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1));
        list.add(u);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public List<Form> getForm() {
    String userid5 = Constant.preferences.getString(Constant.USERID, "");
    List<Form> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM form", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Form u=new Form(cursor.getString(0),cursor.getString(1),cursor.getString(2),cursor.getString(3),cursor.getString(4),cursor.getString(5),cursor.getString(6),cursor.getString(7),cursor.getString(8),cursor.getString(9),cursor.getString(10),cursor.getString(11),cursor.getString(12),cursor.getString(13),cursor.getString(14),cursor.getString(15),cursor.getString(16),cursor.getString(17),cursor.getString(18),cursor.getString(19),cursor.getString(20),cursor.getString(21),cursor.getString(22),cursor.getString(23),cursor.getString(24),cursor.getString(25),cursor.getString(26),cursor.getString(27),cursor.getString(28),cursor.getString(29),cursor.getString(30),cursor.getString(31),cursor.getString(32),cursor.getString(33));
        list.add(u);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}

public List<Bcc> getBcc() {
    String userid5 = Constant.preferences.getString(Constant.USERID, "");
    List<Bcc> list = new ArrayList<>();
    Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM bcc", null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    while (!cursor.isAfterLast()) {
        Bcc u=new Bcc(cursor.getString(0), cursor.getString(1), cursor.getString(2), cursor.getString(3), cursor.getString(4), cursor.getString(5), cursor.getString(6), cursor.getString(7), cursor.getString(8), cursor.getString(9), cursor.getString(10), cursor.getString(11), cursor.getString(12), cursor.getString(13), cursor.getString(14), cursor.getString(15), cursor.getString(16), cursor.getString(17), cursor.getString(18), cursor.getString(19), cursor.getString(20), cursor.getString(21), cursor.getString(22), cursor.getString(23), cursor.getString(24), cursor.getString(25), cursor.getString(26), cursor.getString(27), cursor.getString(28), cursor.getString(29), cursor.getString(30), cursor.getString(31), cursor.getString(32), cursor.getString(33), cursor.getString(34), cursor.getString(35), cursor.getString(36), cursor.getString(37), cursor.getString(38), cursor.getString(39), cursor.getString(40), cursor.getString(41), cursor.getString(42), cursor.getString(43), cursor.getString(44), cursor.getString(45), cursor.getString(46), cursor.getString(47), cursor.getString(48), cursor.getString(49), cursor.getString(50), cursor.getString(51), cursor.getString(52), cursor.getString(53), cursor.getString(54), cursor.getString(55), cursor.getString(56), cursor.getString(57), cursor.getString(58), cursor.getString(59), cursor.getString(60), cursor.getString(61), cursor.getString(62), cursor.getString(63), cursor.getString(64), cursor.getString(65), cursor.getString(66), cursor.getString(67), cursor.getString(68), cursor.getString(69), cursor.getString(70), cursor.getString(71), cursor.getString(72), cursor.getString(73), cursor.getString(74), cursor.getString(75), cursor.getString(76), cursor.getString(77), cursor.getString(78), cursor.getString(79), cursor.getString(80), cursor.getString(81), cursor.getString(82), cursor.getString(83));
        list.add(u);
        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
    cursor.close();
    return list;
}
}
```

I also forgot to mention I have imported the table from mySQL to SQLite in Navicat

Comment: show us the code

Comment: Code has been added

Comment: How has what is in Navicat got into the App? You may wish to make use of the [logDatabaseInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues) which would very likely show that the App is not in sync with what is in NaviCat and that the table **bcc** does not exist. The fix could be as simple as deleting the App's Data or uninstalling the App.

Comment: Thanks a million, true it was that simple to uninstall and install the app again.

Answer (score -1):

The process that you need to follow to find out what is giving you this error is you need to dump all the tables that are currently setup in the database. I am assuming that it could be something as simple and typo.

Comment: Debugging suggestions should be comments, not answers. You have enough rep now to comment on the question.