# Reading a database from the assets folder

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-database

I have a db file in asset folder how can I use it. I must be able to read and write the database file 
If I use

> `SqliteDatabase.open(context.openassest().open(filrname),null);`
>   Exception db file not found 
>   Don't check. The syntax I have done correctly in my lap see the content

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To utilise a packaged database (i.e one included as an asset) for full use the database must be unzipped (automatic) and copied to a suitable location (most often `data/data/<package_name>/databases/<database_name>` where `<package_name>` and `<database_name>` will be according to the App's package name and the database name respectiviely).

To "package" the database is should be included in the assets folder and preferably to a databases folder (*required if using SQLiteAssetHelper without modification*).

Additionally the copy must be done before actually opening the database after which it can then be opened.

### Utilising SQLiteAssetHelper

1. The very first step is to create the database to be packaged, this is not going to be covered, as there are numerous tools available. For this example the database is a file named **test.db**
2. You should then create your project in this case the Project has been called **DBtest** with a Compnay Domian as **com.DBtest** so the package name is **dbtest.com.dbtest**.
3. The next stage is to copy the database into the assets folder.

   1. Creating the **assets** folder in the **src/main** folder, if it doesn't already exist.
   2. Creating the **databases"" folder in the **assets** folder, if it doesn't already exist.
   3. Copying the database file (***test.db*** in this example) into the database folder.

      - [image]
4. The next stage is to setup the project to utilise the SQLiteAssetHelper by including it in the App's **build.gradle**.

   1. Edit the **build.gradle** in the **App** folder.
   2. Add the line `implementation 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:2.0.1'` within the dependencies section.
   3. Click **Sync Now**

[image]

---

5. Create a class that is a subclass of the newly/now available SQLiteAssethelper class. For this exercise it will be called **DBHelper**.

   1. Right Click the **MainActivity** java class, select New and then Java Class.
   2. In the Name field input **DBHelper**.
   3. In the SuperClass field start typing SQLiteAsset (by now the SQliteAssetHelper class will be selectable), so select it. It should resolve to be:-
   4. Click OK.
      [image]
6. Create the constructor for the DBHelper class along the lines of

:-

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "test.db"; //<<<< must be same as file name
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;

    public DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DBNAME,null,DBVERSION);
    }
}
```

7. Create an instance of the DBHelper and then access the database.

   1. ***Note*** for ease another class called **CommonSQLiteUtilities**, as copied from [Are there any methods that assist with resolving common SQLite issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)
   2. Create an instance of the DBHelper cclass using something along the lines of

      - `DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);`
   3. using the CommonSQLiteUtilities the database was accessed using :-

      - `CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase());`
   4. The MainActivity in full became

:-

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        DBHelper mDBHlpr = new DBHelper(this);
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(mDBHlpr.getWritableDatabase());
    }
}
```

---

The result was a successful run logging :-

```
04-11 06:12:55.091 1401-1401/dbtest.com.dbtest W/SQLiteAssetHelper: copying database from assets...
    database copy complete
04-11 06:12:55.123 1401-1401/dbtest.com.dbtest I/SQLiteAssetHelper: successfully opened database test.db
04-11 06:12:55.127 1401-1401/dbtest.com.dbtest D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/dbtest.com.dbtest/databases/test.db
    Database Version = 1
    Table Name = mytable Created Using = CREATE TABLE mytable (
        _id INTEGER PRIAMRY KEY, 
        mydata TEXT, 
        inserted INTEGER DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
    )
    Table = mytable ColumnName = _id ColumnType = INTEGER PRIAMRY KEY Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = mytable ColumnName = mydata ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = mytable ColumnName = inserted ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
    Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
```

- The first two lines are from **`SQliteAssethelper`**, the rest are from the **`logDatabaseInfo`** method of the **`CommonSQLiteUtilities`** class.
- On subsequnt runs the database will not be copied as it already exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can copy the database from your assets to the databases folder upon installation, and then use it from there.

```
/data/data/<Your-Application-Package-Name>/databases/<your-database-name>
```

Comment: Bro any video tutorial
If I make to copy after installation.