# Android Studio databaseHelper No such column

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-studio

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    //DATABASE NAME,TABLES' NAMES
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "book_db.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
    private static final String BOOKS_TABLE = "books";//<--TABLE
    private static final String BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "categories";//<--TABLE
    private static final String AUTHORS_TABLE = "authorsTable";//<--TABLE

    //BOOK_TABLE ATTRIBUTES
    private static final String BOOK_KEY = "bookKey";
    private static final String BOOK_TITLE = "_bookTitle";
    private static final String PERSONAL_RATING = "_personalRating";
    private static final String AVERAGE_RATING = "_averageRating";
    private static final String IMAGE_DATA = "imageData";
    private static final String BOOK_ID = "bookId";
    private static final String GOOGLE_ID = "googleId";
    private static final String ISBN_10 = "isbn10";
    private static final String ISBN_13 = "isbn13";
    private static final String BOOK_COVER_URL = "bookCoverUrl";
    private static final String DESCRIPTION = "description";
    private static final String CALLBACK_URL = "callBackUrl";
    private static final String PREVIEW_URL = "previewUrl";
    private static final String BUY_URL = "buyUrl";
    private static final String PAGE_COUNT = "pageCount";
    private static final String PUBLISHED_DATE = "publishedDate";
    private static final String IS_BOOK_COLLECTION = "isBookCollection";
    private static final String IS_BOOK_READ = "isBookRead";
    private static final String IS_BOOK_IN_WHISHLIST = "isBookInWishList";



    //AUTHORS TABLE ATTRIBUTES
    //private static final String GOOGLE_ID = "googleId";     //Already declared above
    private static final String AUTHOR = "author";

    //CATEGORIES TABLE ATTRIBUTES
    //private static final String GOOGLE_ID = "googleId";     //Already declared above
    private static final String CATEGORY = "category";

    private static Database mInstance;

    public static synchronized Database getInstance(Context c) {
        if (mInstance == null ) {
            mInstance = new Database(c);
        }
        return mInstance;
    }


    private Database(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
        //TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }


    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase) {

        //BOOKS TABLE CREATE
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + BOOKS_TABLE + " ( " + BOOK_TITLE + " TEXT, " + BOOK_KEY + " TEXT," + PERSONAL_RATING + " REAL,"
            + AVERAGE_RATING + " REAL," +
            BOOK_ID + " TEXT," + GOOGLE_ID +" TEXT," + ISBN_13 + " TEXT," + ISBN_10 + " TEXT," + BOOK_COVER_URL + " TEXT," + DESCRIPTION + " TEXT," +
            CALLBACK_URL + " TEXT," + PREVIEW_URL + " TEXT," + BUY_URL + " TEXT," + PAGE_COUNT + " INT," + PUBLISHED_DATE + " TEXT,"
            + IS_BOOK_COLLECTION + " INT," + IS_BOOK_READ + " INT," + IS_BOOK_IN_WHISHLIST  + " INT," + IMAGE_DATA + " BLOB," + " PRIMARY KEY(" + BOOK_KEY +"));");
        //No boolean type in SQLite, INT used instead.

        //CATEGORIES TABLE CREATE
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + AUTHORS_TABLE + " ( " + BOOK_KEY + " TEXT, "   + CATEGORY +
            " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("+ BOOK_KEY +"," + CATEGORY +"));");

        //AUTHORS TABLE CREATE
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(" CREATE TABLE " + BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE + " ( " + BOOK_KEY + " TEXT, "   + AUTHOR +
            " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY("+ BOOK_KEY +"," + AUTHOR +"));");
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase, int i, int i1) {
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BOOKS_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
        sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + AUTHORS_TABLE);
        onCreate(sqLiteDatabase);
    }

    /**
     *  This method adds a Book to the database
     * @param book
     * @return
     */
    public boolean addRecord(Book book){

        boolean resultBooksTable = false;
        boolean resultAuthorsTable = false;
        boolean resultCategoriesTable = false;

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues booksTableValues = new ContentValues();

        //BOOK TABLE VALUES   \\\\------///
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_KEY,book.getKey());
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_TITLE,book.getBookTitle());
        booksTableValues.put(AVERAGE_RATING,book.getAverageRating());
        booksTableValues.put(PERSONAL_RATING,book.getPersonalRating());
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_ID,book.getId());
        booksTableValues.put(GOOGLE_ID,book.getGoogleID());
        booksTableValues.put(ISBN_13,book.getISBN13());
        booksTableValues.put(ISBN_10,book.getISBN10());
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_COVER_URL,book.getBookCoverURL());
        booksTableValues.put(DESCRIPTION,book.getDescription());
        booksTableValues.put(CALLBACK_URL,book.getCallbackURL());
        booksTableValues.put(PREVIEW_URL,book.getPreviewURL());
        booksTableValues.put(BUY_URL,book.getBuyURL());
        booksTableValues.put(PAGE_COUNT,book.getPageCount());
        booksTableValues.put(PUBLISHED_DATE,book.getPublishedDate());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_COLLECTION,book.isBookInCollection());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_READ,book.isBookRead());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_IN_WHISHLIST,book.isBookInWishlist());
        booksTableValues.put(IMAGE_DATA,book.getByteArray());

        //Inserting into BOOKS_TABLE

        try{//Try inserting into BOOKS_TABLE

            sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(BOOKS_TABLE,null, booksTableValues);
            resultBooksTable = true;
        }catch (SQLiteConstraintException alreadyInserted){
            //Row is already inserted
        }

        //CATEGORY Table values
        ContentValues CategoriesTableValues = new ContentValues();
        CategoriesTableValues.put(BOOK_KEY,book.getKey());

        //AUTHORS_TABLE values
        ContentValues authorsTableValues = new ContentValues();
        authorsTableValues.put(BOOK_KEY,book.getKey());

        //Insert categories into BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE
        int i = 0;
        if (book.getCategories().length >= 0) try {//Try inserting into CATEGORIES_TABLE

            for (i = 0; i < book.getCategories().length; i++) {


                CategoriesTableValues.put(CATEGORY, book.getCategories()[i]);
                sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE, null, CategoriesTableValues);
            }

            resultCategoriesTable = true;

        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException alreadyInserted) {
            //Row is already inserted
        }

        //Insert authors into AUTHORS_TABLE
        i = 0;
        if (book.getAuthor().length >= 0) try {//Try inserting into CATEGORIES_TABLE

            for (i = 0; i < book.getAuthor().length; i++) {


                CategoriesTableValues.put(AUTHOR, book.getAuthor()[i]);
                sqLiteDatabase.insertOrThrow(AUTHORS_TABLE, null, authorsTableValues);
            }

            resultAuthorsTable = true;

        } catch (SQLiteConstraintException alreadyInserted) {
            //Row is already inserted
        }


        return resultBooksTable && resultAuthorsTable && resultCategoriesTable;

    }

    /**
     * Packs all books from database to a bookList and returns the list
     * @return
     */
    public ArrayList<Book> getSavedBooksList(){

        ArrayList<Book> savedBooksList = new ArrayList<Book>();

        Book book=new Book();//First declaration so it's not undeclared.



        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        //Query
        String q = "SELECT * FROM " + BOOKS_TABLE;//The entire table
        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(q,null);

        /////->One iteration for each book

        try{
            //Index of each column
            int bookKeyIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_KEY);
            int titleIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_TITLE);
            int averageRatingIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(AVERAGE_RATING);
            int personalRatingIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PERSONAL_RATING);
            int IdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_ID);
            int googleIdIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(GOOGLE_ID);
            int isbn13Index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ISBN_13);
            int isbn10Index = cursor.getColumnIndex(ISBN_10);
            int urlIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BOOK_COVER_URL);
            int descriptionIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(DESCRIPTION);
            int callbackUrlIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(CALLBACK_URL);
            int previewUrlIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PREVIEW_URL);
            int buyUrlIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(BUY_URL);
            int pageCountIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PAGE_COUNT);
            int dateIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(PUBLISHED_DATE);
            int isBookCollectionIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(IS_BOOK_COLLECTION);
            int isBookReadIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(IS_BOOK_READ);
            int isBookInWishlistIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(IS_BOOK_IN_WHISHLIST);
            int bookCoverIndex = cursor.getColumnIndex(IMAGE_DATA);



            cursor.moveToPosition(-1);

            while(cursor.moveToNext()){


                book = new Book();

                book.setId(cursor.getString(IdIndex));
                book.setAverageRating(averageRatingIndex);
                book.setPersonalRating(personalRatingIndex);
                book.setBookTitle(cursor.getString(titleIndex));
                book.setBookCoverURL(cursor.getString(urlIndex));
                book.setDescription(cursor.getString(descriptionIndex));
                book.setGoogleID(cursor.getString(googleIdIndex));
                book.setCallbackURL(cursor.getString(callbackUrlIndex));
                book.setPreviewURL(cursor.getString(previewUrlIndex));
                book.setBuyURL(cursor.getString(buyUrlIndex));
                book.setPageCount(cursor.getInt(pageCountIndex));
                book.setPublishedDate(cursor.getString(dateIndex));
                book.setISBN13(cursor.getString(isbn13Index));
                book.setISBN10(cursor.getString(isbn10Index));
                book.setBookInCollection(1 == cursor.getInt(isBookCollectionIndex));//1==int var (converts int to boolean)
                book.setBookRead(1 == cursor.getInt(isBookReadIndex));//SQLite doesn't support boolean.
                book.setBookInWishlist(1 == cursor.getInt(isBookInWishlistIndex));
                book.setBitmapFromByteArray(cursor.getBlob(bookCoverIndex));


                //Query of categories of the current book
                String q1 = null;

                q1 = "SELECT * FROM " + BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE
                    + " WHERE " + BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE + "." + BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() + "'";


                Cursor cursorCategories = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(q1,null);

                //Query of authors of the current book
                String q2 = null;
                q2 = "SELECT * FROM " + AUTHORS_TABLE
                    + " WHERE " + AUTHORS_TABLE + "." + BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() + "'";

                Cursor cursorAuthors = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(q2,null);

                int categoryIndex = cursorCategories.getColumnIndex(CATEGORY);

                int authorIndex = cursorAuthors.getColumnIndex(AUTHOR);

                String[] categories = new String[cursorCategories.getCount()];

                String[] authors = new String[cursorAuthors.getCount()];

                cursorCategories.moveToPosition(-1);
                cursorAuthors.moveToPosition(-1);

                //Create String[] of categories
                while(cursorCategories.moveToNext()) {
                    categories[cursorCategories.getPosition()] = cursorCategories.getString(categoryIndex);

                }
                book.setCategories(categories);

                //Create String[] of authors
                while(cursorAuthors.moveToNext()) {
                    authors[cursorAuthors.getPosition()] = cursorAuthors.getString(authorIndex);

                }
                book.setAuthor(authors);

                //Add book to list
                savedBooksList.add(book);
            }
        }catch (Exception outOfBounds){

        }
        finally {
            cursor.close();
        }




        return savedBooksList;
    }

    /**
     * This method deletes a row from the database
     * @param book
     * @return
     */
    public boolean deleteRecord(Book book){

        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();

        int numOfRowsDeleted = 0;

        try{//Delete everything for this book from categories table
            numOfRowsDeleted += sqLiteDatabase.delete(BOOK_CATEGORIES_TABLE, BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() +"'", null);

        }catch (Exception noSuchColumn){
            //No such column
            //numOfRowsDeleted = 0;
        }

        try{
            numOfRowsDeleted += sqLiteDatabase.delete(BOOKS_TABLE, BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() +"'", null);

        }catch (Exception noSuchColumn){
            //No such column
            //numOfRowsDeleted = 0;
        }

        try{//Delete everything for this book from authors table
            numOfRowsDeleted += sqLiteDatabase.delete(AUTHORS_TABLE, BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() +"'", null);

        }catch (Exception noSuchColumn){
            //No such column
            //numOfRowsDeleted = 0;
        }

        if(numOfRowsDeleted > 0){//If 1 row at least deleted return true
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }


    }

    /** Returns true if book exists in the database.
     *  Returns false if it doesn't.
     *
     * @param book
     * @return
     */
    public boolean isBookSaved(Book book){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        String q = "SELECT * FROM " + BOOKS_TABLE
            + " WHERE "
            + BOOK_KEY + "='" + book.getKey() + "'";



        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(q,null);

        return cursor.moveToFirst();

    }

    /**
     *   UPDATE PERSONAL RATING
     *   The only variable for update is PERSONAL_RATING
     *   The update takes place only on BOOKS_TABLE.
     *   Other tables don't have to be updated.
     * @param book
     * @return
     */
    public boolean updateRecord(Book book){
        SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        boolean result = false;
        ContentValues booksTableValues = new ContentValues();
        //BOOK TABLE VALUES   \\\\------///
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_TITLE,book.getBookTitle());
        booksTableValues.put(AVERAGE_RATING,book.getAverageRating());
        booksTableValues.put(PERSONAL_RATING,book.getPersonalRating());
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_ID,book.getId());
        booksTableValues.put(GOOGLE_ID,book.getGoogleID());
        booksTableValues.put(ISBN_13,book.getISBN13());
        booksTableValues.put(ISBN_10,book.getISBN10());
        booksTableValues.put(BOOK_COVER_URL,book.getBookCoverURL());
        booksTableValues.put(DESCRIPTION,book.getDescription());
        booksTableValues.put(CALLBACK_URL,book.getCallbackURL());
        booksTableValues.put(PREVIEW_URL,book.getPreviewURL());
        booksTableValues.put(BUY_URL,book.getBuyURL());
        booksTableValues.put(PAGE_COUNT,book.getPageCount());
        booksTableValues.put(PUBLISHED_DATE,book.getPublishedDate());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_COLLECTION,book.isBookInCollection());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_READ,book.isBookRead());
        booksTableValues.put(IS_BOOK_IN_WHISHLIST,book.isBookInWishlist());
        booksTableValues.put(IMAGE_DATA,book.getByteArray());

        String q = null;

        q = "SELECT * FROM " + BOOKS_TABLE +" WHERE " + BOOK_KEY + " ='" + book.getKey() + "'";

        Cursor cursor = sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(q,null);
        if(cursor.moveToFirst()){
            sqLiteDatabase.update(BOOKS_TABLE, booksTableValues, q, null);
            result = true;
        }
        cursor.close();
        //sqLiteDatabase.close();
        return result;
    }
}
```

The following errors pop up :

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: table books has no column named isbn10 (code 1): , while compiling: INSERT INTO books(isbn10,googleId,isBookRead,bookCoverUrl,_bookTitle,buyUrl,isBookCollection,publishedDate,previewUrl,pageCount,_personalRating,bookKey,isbn13,isBookInWishList,callBackUrl,description,bookId,imageData,_averageRating) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: bookKey (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM books WHERE bookKey='4593490'
at com.example.xrhstos.bookapp.Database.isBookSaved(Database.java:381)
```

Comment: PLEASE MAKE THAT READABLE

Comment: try deleting the App's Data, uninstalling the App or changing `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);` and then rerunning the App.

Answer (score 1):

The likely cause of the **column** not found is because of the common misconception that the SQLiteOpenHelper's `onCreate` method runs every time an instance of a subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper (aka the DatabaseHelper **Database**) is created.

However, The `onCreate` method is only invoked once for the lifetime of the database. As such any changes made to the structure of the database within the code invoked by the `onCreate` method will not be applied unless the database is deleted (or if the `onCreate` method is invoked some other way).

The easy fix is to delete the database in which case the `onCreate` method will then run. The database can be easily deleted by deleting the App's Data or by uninstalling the App (both delete the App's data and hence the database).

If the `onUpgrade` method of the Database Helper has been written to DROP all the table(s) and to then invoke the `onCreate` method, then this can also be used. The `onUpgrade` method is called by the Database Helper when the Database's Version (4th parameter of the super constructor) is increased. So this method entails increasing the version number.

In all 3 of the above the existing data will be lost. If the data needs to be retained then the process is more complex and would also be dependent upon what structural changes were being made.

### The Fix

To fix the issue do 1 of the following :-

- Delete the App's data.
- Uninstall the App.
- Change

  - `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);` to
  - `super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 2);`

And then rerun the App.

#### Note

- This is the most likely/common cause.
- Thorough examination testing of your code has not been undertaken.
- If the problem persists then indicate as such and a more thorough examination of the code could be undertaken.

### Additional

After actually testing you code, it is highly likely that the cause is as above. i.e. **without any modification to the table create SQL the tables were created**, thus very strongly suggesting that the cause is as above.

Using your code, with removal of the methods that utilise other objects such as Books, and utilising the methods from [Are there any methods that assist with resolving common SQLite issues? - Addition 1 - logDatabaseInfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)

Then the reported missing columns **isbn10** and **bookKey** exist as expected as per :-

```
        Table = books ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1

        Table = books ColumnName = isbn10 ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0


        Table = authorsTable ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1

        Table = categories ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
```

The full output the above was extracted from was :-

```
04-24 00:29:08.459 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/soanswers.soanswers/databases/book_db.db
    PRAGMA -  sqlite_version = 3.7.11
    PRAGMA -  user_version = 1
    PRAGMA -  encoding = UTF-8
    PRAGMA -  auto_vacuum = 1
    PRAGMA -  cache_size = 2000
    PRAGMA -  foreign_keys = 0
04-24 00:29:08.463 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: PRAGMA -  freelist_count = 0
    PRAGMA -  ignore_check_constraints = 0
    PRAGMA -  journal_mode = persist
    PRAGMA -  journal_size_limit = 524288
    PRAGMA -  locking_mode = normal
    PRAGMA -  max_page_count = 1073741823
    PRAGMA -  page_count = 9
    PRAGMA -  page_size = 4096
    PRAGMA -  recursive_triggers = 0
    PRAGMA -  reverse_unordered_selects = 0
04-24 00:29:08.467 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: PRAGMA -  secure_delete = 0
    PRAGMA -  synchronous = 2
    PRAGMA -  temp_store = 0
    PRAGMA -  wal_autocheckpoint = 100
    Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
    Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Number of Indexes = 0
    Number of Foreign Keys = 0
    Number of Triggers = 0
    Table Name = books Created Using = CREATE TABLE books ( _bookTitle TEXT, bookKey TEXT,_personalRating REAL,_averageRating REAL,bookId TEXT,googleId TEXT,isbn13 TEXT,isbn10 TEXT,bookCoverUrl TEXT,description TEXT,callBackUrl TEXT,previewUrl TEXT,buyUrl TEXT,pageCount INT,publishedDate TEXT,isBookCollection INT,isBookRead INT,isBookInWishList INT,imageData BLOB, PRIMARY KEY(bookKey))
    Table = books ColumnName = _bookTitle ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
04-24 00:29:08.471 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = books ColumnName = _personalRating ColumnType = REAL Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = _averageRating ColumnType = REAL Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = bookId ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = googleId ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = isbn13 ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = isbn10 ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = bookCoverUrl ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = description ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = callBackUrl ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = previewUrl ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = buyUrl ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = pageCount ColumnType = INT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = publishedDate ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = isBookCollection ColumnType = INT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = isBookRead ColumnType = INT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = isBookInWishList ColumnType = INT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = books ColumnName = imageData ColumnType = BLOB Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Number of Indexes = 1
    INDEX NAME = sqlite_autoindex_books_1
        Sequence = 0
        Unique   = true
        Index Origin indicator unsupported
        Index Partial indicator unsupported
        INDEX COLUMN = bookKey COLUMN ID = 1 SEQUENCE = 0
    Number of Foreign Keys = 0
    Number of Triggers = 0
    Table Name = authorsTable Created Using = CREATE TABLE authorsTable ( bookKey TEXT, category TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(bookKey,category))
    Table = authorsTable ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
    Table = authorsTable ColumnName = category ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
    Number of Indexes = 1
    INDEX NAME = sqlite_autoindex_authorsTable_1
        Sequence = 0
        Unique   = true
        Index Origin indicator unsupported
        Index Partial indicator unsupported
        INDEX COLUMN = bookKey COLUMN ID = 0 SEQUENCE = 0
        INDEX COLUMN = category COLUMN ID = 1 SEQUENCE = 1
04-24 00:29:08.475 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: Number of Foreign Keys = 0
    Number of Triggers = 0
    Table Name = categories Created Using = CREATE TABLE categories ( bookKey TEXT, author TEXT, PRIMARY KEY(bookKey,author))
    Table = categories ColumnName = bookKey ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
    Table = categories ColumnName = author ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
    Number of Indexes = 1
    INDEX NAME = sqlite_autoindex_categories_1
        Sequence = 0
        Unique   = true
        Index Origin indicator unsupported
        Index Partial indicator unsupported
        INDEX COLUMN = bookKey COLUMN ID = 0 SEQUENCE = 0
        INDEX COLUMN = author COLUMN ID = 1 SEQUENCE = 1
    Number of Foreign Keys = 0
    Number of Triggers = 0
    logCursorColumns invoked. Cursor has the following 19 columns.
    Column Name 1 is _bookTitle
    Column Name 2 is bookKey
    Column Name 3 is _personalRating
    Column Name 4 is _averageRating
    Column Name 5 is bookId
    Column Name 6 is googleId
    Column Name 7 is isbn13
    Column Name 8 is isbn10
    Column Name 9 is bookCoverUrl
    Column Name 10 is description
    Column Name 11 is callBackUrl
    Column Name 12 is previewUrl
    Column Name 13 is buyUrl
    Column Name 14 is pageCount
    Column Name 15 is publishedDate
04-24 00:29:08.479 1263-1263/soanswers.soanswers D/SQLITE_CSU: Column Name 16 is isBookCollection
    Column Name 17 is isBookRead
    Column Name 18 is isBookInWishList
    Column Name 19 is imageData
    logCursorColumns invoked. Cursor has the following 2 columns.
    Column Name 1 is bookKey
    Column Name 2 is author
    logCursorColumns invoked. Cursor has the following 2 columns.
    Column Name 1 is bookKey
    Column Name 2 is category
```

Comment: Thank you for your analytical answer, it solved my problem and made understand more about the android SQLite database.