# App crashes without any changes done

Tags: android, android-studio, android-activity

This post is related to [Creating multiple Tables and inserting Data into them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50544190/creating-multiple-tables-and-inserting-data-into-them)
So I fixed the issue I had with only one table getting created. But now the app chrashes when I try to switch activities. My MainActivity is still working.

This is one of the classes/activities that crashes. The other one is similar, the only differences are the names of the buttons and textedits.

```
public class FachErstellen extends AppCompatActivity {

DatabaseHelper myDb;
EditText editTextFachName;
EditText editTextFachKuerzel;
EditText editTextFachRaum;
EditText editTextFachLehrer;
Button buttonFachSpeichern;








@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.fach_erstellen_activity);

    myDb = new DatabaseHelper(this);
    myDb.fuegeNeueTabellenHinzu();
    editTextFachName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFachName);
    editTextFachKuerzel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFachKuerzel);
    editTextFachRaum = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFachRaum);
    editTextFachLehrer = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextFachLehrer);
    buttonFachSpeichern = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonFachSpeichern);

    addFach();
    zeigeFaecher();


}

public void addFach(){
    buttonFachSpeichern.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            boolean istGespeichert = myDb.speichereFach(editTextFachName.getText().toString(),
                    editTextFachKuerzel.getText().toString(),
                    editTextFachRaum.getText().toString(),
                    editTextFachLehrer.getText().toString());
            if (istGespeichert==true){
                Toast.makeText(FachErstellen.this, "Fach wurde gespeichert.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(FachErstellen.this, "Fach konnte nicht gespeichert werden.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
    });

}

public void zeigeFaecher(){
    buttonFaecherAnzeigen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Cursor res = myDb.zeigeFaecher();
            if (res.getCount() == 0) {
                zeigeNachricht("Fehler", "Keine Fächer gefunden");
                return;
            }

            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            while (res.moveToNext()){
                buffer.append("ID:" + res.getString(0)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Fach: " + res.getString(1)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Kürzel: " + res.getString(2)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Raum: " + res.getString(3)+"\n");
                buffer.append("Lehrer: " + res.getString(4)+"\n\n");
            }

            zeigeNachricht("Fächer", buffer.toString());
        }
    });
}

public void zeigeNachricht(String title, String Nachricht){
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCancelable(true);
    builder.setTitle(title);
    builder.setMessage(Nachricht);
    builder.show();

}
```

--
and following the gradle file

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {

    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.2'


        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

--

and the crash info

```
    Increasing code cache capacity to 128KB
05-29 15:15:28.150 15952-15952/jannikokan.de.stundenplan D/MeineAPP: DB angelegt
05-29 15:15:28.154 15952-15952/jannikokan.de.stundenplan E/SQLiteLog: (1) AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
05-29 15:15:28.154 15952-15952/jannikokan.de.stundenplan D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
05-29 15:15:28.155 15952-15952/jannikokan.de.stundenplan E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: jannikokan.de.stundenplan, PID: 15952
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{jannikokan.de.stundenplan/jannikokan.de.stundenplan.LehrerErstellen}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1): , while compiling: create table Lehrer_table(ID_LINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LEHRERNAMETEXT,LEHRERKUERZELTEXT,LEHRERRAUMTEXT,LEHRERMAILTEXT)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2646)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: AUTOINCREMENT is only allowed on an INTEGER PRIMARY KEY (code 1): , while compiling: create table Lehrer_table(ID_LINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LEHRERNAMETEXT,LEHRERKUERZELTEXT,LEHRERRAUMTEXT,LEHRERMAILTEXT)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:889)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:500)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:31)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.executeSql(SQLiteDatabase.java:1677)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.execSQL(SQLiteDatabase.java:1608)
        at jannikokan.de.stundenplan.DatabaseHelper.CheckeUndErstelleTabelle(DatabaseHelper.java:114)
        at jannikokan.de.stundenplan.DatabaseHelper.erstelleTabellenDieNichtExistieren(DatabaseHelper.java:98)
        at jannikokan.de.stundenplan.DatabaseHelper.fuegeNeueTabellenHinzu(DatabaseHelper.java:80)
        at jannikokan.de.stundenplan.LehrerErstellen.onCreate(LehrerErstellen.java:36)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6662)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1118)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2599)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2707) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1460) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6077) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:866) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:756) 
05-29 15:15:28.155 1595-1606/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity jannikokan.de.stundenplan/.LehrerErstellen
05-29 15:15:28.158 1595-1606/? W/ActivityManager:   Force finishing activity jannikokan.de.stundenplan/.SliderActivityActivity
05-29 15:15:28.196 1595-1636/? I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
05-29 15:15:28.196 1595-1636/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
05-29 15:15:28.196 1595-1636/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
05-29 15:15:28.196 1595-1636/? D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
05-29 15:15:28.200 1595-1636/? D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xa350f6c0: maj 2 min 0 rcv 2
05-29 15:15:28.211 1595-1636/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa350f6c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x974e53b0)
05-29 15:15:28.218 1595-1636/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa350f6c0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0x974e53b0)
05-29 15:15:28.660 1595-1608/? W/ActivityManager: Activity pause timeout for ActivityRecord{17375b u0 jannikokan.de.stundenplan/.LehrerErstellen t103 f}
05-29 15:15:28.779 1996-2119/? D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xa5e052a0: ver 2 0 (tinfo 0xa5e03630)
05-29 15:15:29.294 1996-2119/? W/OpenGLRenderer: Incorrectly called buildLayer on View: ShortcutAndWidgetContainer, destroying layer...
05-29 15:15:31.327 1353-1378/? W/audio_hw_generic: Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 7930259 , only wrote 7777440
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: what is the content of your gradle file ? have you some dependencie like constraintlayout ... ?

Comment: See [ask]. Shows us the crash info as text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cause of this exception is that you have something other then `?? INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT` for a column when creating the table.

More specifically you have :-

```
create table Lehrer_table(ID_LINTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LEHRERNAMETEXT,LEHRERKUERZELTEXT,LEHRERRAUMTEXT,LEHRERMAILTEXT)
```

This should likely be :-

```
create table Lehrer_table(ID_L INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,LEHRERNAMETEXT,LEHRERKUERZELTEXT,LEHRERRAUMTEXT,LEHRERMAILTEXT)
```

i.e. a space has been added between **`ID_L`** and **`INTEGER`** so **`ID_LINTEGER`** becomes **`ID_L INTEGER`**.

Saying that you using `AUTOINCREMENT` is very likely unnecessary and detrimental as it consumes more resources.

All that `AUTOINCREMENT` does is ensure that the next **id** will be greater than the previous (it very likely will be anyway until you reached 9223372036854775807 rows). Should that number be reached with `AUTOINCREMENT` you would then not be able to insert rows as an insert would have an **SQLITE_FULL** exception. Whilst, there is a chance that without `AUTOINCREMENT` that a now unused id will be assigned.

To quote the SQLIte documentation :-

> 1. The AUTOINCREMENT keyword imposes extra CPU, memory, disk space, and
>      disk I/O overhead and should be avoided if not strictly needed. It is
>      usually not needed.
> 2. In SQLite, a column with type INTEGER PRIMARY KEY is an alias for the
>      ROWID (except in WITHOUT ROWID tables) which is always a 64-bit signed
>      integer.
> 3. On an INSERT, if the ROWID or INTEGER PRIMARY KEY column is not
>      explicitly given a value, then it will be filled automatically with an
>      unused integer, usually one more than the largest ROWID currently in
>      use. This is true regardless of whether or not the AUTOINCREMENT
>      keyword is used.
> 4. If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that
>      changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse
>      of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the
>      purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from
>      previously deleted rows.

As such I'd suggest using :-

```
create table Lehrer_table(ID_L INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,LEHRERNAMETEXT,LEHRERKUERZELTEXT,LEHRERRAUMTEXT,LEHRERMAILTEXT)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. If its OK for you  I have another issue now :). While inserting data in the table i got a crash info that there wehre no column in the table.

Comment: Did you (can you afford to lose existing data) delete the App's data (settings/apps clear/delete data) and rerun? A very common cause of column not found, as the `onCreate` method only runs when the database is first created.

Comment: Thank you all, especially @MikeT  for helping my code is working now.

Comment: @jungWombat that's great, can you tick the question as answered.