# Android Studio: Database created, but no table

Tags: database, android-studio, sqlite

I am a newbie at programming so please bear with me (I am taking an online course).

I am at a point in the lesson where we were supposed to create a database in a java class and a table called "pets" would get created in the onCreate method of the main activity (called CatalogActivity).

At this point, I have already downloaded the app exactly in the form it is supposed to be (to make sure I haven't made a mistake before in my code), but when I run the app on the emulator, no table gets created.

The idea is, when I run the app, the database called shelter.db should get created and in it, the table called "pets". This table is defined in the PetDbHelper.java class.

When searching in Android Studio terminal, I see no tables in shelter.db. So I downloaded shelter.db to my PC and opened it with SQL browser - still no "pets" table. Looks like for some reason, the table doesn't get created :(

I don't know why as I seem to be following all the instructions to the point.
Does anyone have advice how to fix this, please?

Here is a link to the code: https://github.com/soralka/PetsApp_error

Thanks in advance!

Soralka

Here's the LOG when I use the CommonSQLiteUtilities class:

```
07-18 19:37:44.344 15867-15867/? I/le.android.pet: Not late-enabling -Xcheck:jni (already on)
07-18 19:37:44.416 15867-15867/? W/le.android.pet: Unexpected CPU variant for X86 using defaults: x86
07-18 19:37:44.662 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets I/le.android.pet: The ClassLoaderContext is a special shared library.
07-18 19:37:45.027 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets W/le.android.pet: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
07-18 19:37:45.051 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets I/chatty: uid=10083(com.example.android.pets) identical 10 lines
07-18 19:37:45.051 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets W/le.android.pet: JIT profile information will not be recorded: profile file does not exits.
07-18 19:37:45.137 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets I/InstantRun: starting instant run server: is main process
07-18 19:37:45.840 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets W/le.android.pet: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (light greylist, reflection)
07-18 19:37:45.850 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets W/le.android.pet: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (light greylist, reflection)
07-18 19:37:46.066 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/user/0/com.example.android.pets/databases/shelter.db
07-18 19:37:46.068 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Database Version = 1
07-18 19:37:46.071 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
07-18 19:37:46.073 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
07-18 19:37:46.074 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = pets Created Using = CREATE TABLE pets (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, breed TEXT, gender INTEGER NOT NULL, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
07-18 19:37:46.077 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = pets ColumnName = _id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
07-18 19:37:46.078 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = pets ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
07-18 19:37:46.079 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = pets ColumnName = breed ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = pets ColumnName = gender ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = pets ColumnName = weight ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = 0 PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
07-18 19:37:46.080 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table Name = sqlite_sequence Created Using = CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
07-18 19:37:46.082 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/SQLITE_CSU: Table = sqlite_sequence ColumnName = name ColumnType =  Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = sqlite_sequence ColumnName = seq ColumnType =  Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
07-18 19:37:46.134 15867-15867/com.example.android.pets D/OpenGLRenderer: Skia GL Pipeline
07-18 19:37:46.260 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
07-18 19:37:46.262 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
07-18 19:37:46.262 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
07-18 19:37:46.262 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 1
07-18 19:37:46.262 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets W/OpenGLRenderer: Failed to choose config with EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED, retrying without...
07-18 19:37:46.263 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 0
07-18 19:37:46.284 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets D/EGL_emulation: eglCreateContext: 0xe4fbebc0: maj 3 min 0 rcv 3
07-18 19:37:46.347 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4fbebc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe79c7930)
07-18 19:37:46.534 15867-15886/com.example.android.pets D/EGL_emulation: eglMakeCurrent: 0xe4fbebc0: ver 3 0 (tinfo 0xe79c7930)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based upon your code I can see no issues.

- You may wish to try deleting the App's data, or uninstalling the App adding the line below (or adding the CommonSQLiteUtilities class and adding the two lines that have been added for testing below) and then rerunning the App (this would overcome any issue you may have had that resulted in the database being created but not any tables, in which case the `onCreate` method would not run so any corrective changes (if any) may not have been applied).

Amending the CatalogActivity by adding the line :-

```
displayDatabaseInfo();
```

Results in the EditText being updated as expected (shows 0 rows in pets database).

If the underlying table didn't exist then if you added the line above, you'd experience an exception along the lines of :-

```
07-17 01:28:51.001 1321-1321/pets.pets E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{pets.pets/pets.pets.CatalogActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: notatable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM notatable
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: notatable (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM notatable
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:882)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:493)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.<init>(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1314)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQuery(SQLiteDatabase.java:1253)
        at pets.pets.CatalogActivity.displayDatabaseInfo(CatalogActivity.java:40)
        at pets.pets.CatalogActivity.onCreate(CatalogActivity.java:22)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

- Note forced by changing the table name to **notatable** i.e.

  ```
  Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + "notatable", null);
  ```

Adding the **CommonSQLiteUtilities** class from [Are there any methods that assist with resolving common SQLite issues?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46642269/are-there-any-methods-that-assist-with-resolving-common-sqlite-issues)

and then adding the line :-

```
    CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase());
```

results in the log containing :-

```
07-17 01:36:51.191 1399-1399/? D/SQLITE_CSU: DatabaseList Row 1 Name=main File=/data/data/pets.pets/databases/shelter.db
    Database Version = 1
    Table Name = android_metadata Created Using = CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT)
    Table = android_metadata ColumnName = locale ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table Name = pets Created Using = CREATE TABLE pets (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, breed TEXT, gender INTEGER NOT NULL, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0)
    Table = pets ColumnName = _id ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 1
    Table = pets ColumnName = name ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = pets ColumnName = breed ColumnType = TEXT Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = pets ColumnName = gender ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = pets ColumnName = weight ColumnType = INTEGER Default Value = 0 PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table Name = sqlite_sequence Created Using = CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq)
    Table = sqlite_sequence ColumnName = name ColumnType =  Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
    Table = sqlite_sequence ColumnName = seq ColumnType =  Default Value = null PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = 0
```

Further confirming that the table is created.

The testing above was done using the following code :-

#### CatalogActivity.java

```
public class CatalogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_catalog);


        //displayDatabaseInfo();

        PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        displayDatabaseInfo();
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase());
    }

    /**
     * Temporary helper method to display information in the onscreen TextView about the state of
     * the pets database.
     */
    private void displayDatabaseInfo() {
        // To access our database, we instantiate our subclass of SQLiteOpenHelper
        // and pass the context, which is the current activity.
        PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);

        // Create and/or open a database to read from it
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();

        // Perform this raw SQL query "SELECT * FROM pets"
        // to get a Cursor that contains all rows from the pets table.
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + PetContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME, null);
        try {
            // Display the number of rows in the Cursor (which reflects the number of rows in the
            // pets table in the database).
            TextView displayView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_view_pet);
            displayView.setText("Number of rows in pets database table: " + cursor.getCount());
        } finally {
            // Always close the cursor when you're done reading from it. This releases all its
            // resources and makes it invalid.
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
}
```

#### PetDbHelper.java

```
public class PetDbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = PetDbHelper.class.getSimpleName();

    /**
     * Name of the database file
     */
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "shelter.db";

    /**
     * Database version. If you change the database schema, you must increment the database version.
     */
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    /**
     * Constructs a new instance of {@link PetDbHelper}.
     *
     * @param context of the app
     */
    public PetDbHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database is created for the first time.
     */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        // Create a String that contains the SQL statement to create the pets table
        String SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + PetContract.PetEntry.TABLE_NAME + " ("
                + PetContract.PetEntry._ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_NAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, "
                + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_BREED + " TEXT, "
                + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_GENDER + " INTEGER NOT NULL, "
                + PetContract.PetEntry.COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT + " INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);";
        // Execute the SQL statement
        db.execSQL(SQL_CREATE_PETS_TABLE);
    }

    /**
     * This is called when the database needs to be upgraded.
     */
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // The database is still at version 1, so there's nothing to do be done here.
    }
}
```

#### PetContract.java

```
public final class PetContract {

    private PetContract() {}

    public static final class PetEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "pets";
        public static final String _ID = BaseColumns._ID;
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_BREED = "breed";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_GENDER = "gender";
        public static final String COLUMN_PET_WEIGHT = "weight";

        /* Possible values for gender. */
        public static final int GENDER_UNKNOWN = 0;
        public static final int GENDER_MALE = 1;
        public static final int GENDER_FEMALE = 2;
    }
}
```

#### CommonSQLiteUtilities.java

```
public class CommonSQLiteUtilities {

    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true;
    public static final boolean ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false;

    // SQLite MASTER TABLE definitions
    static final String SQLITE_MASTER = "sqlite_master";
    static final String SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN = "type";
    static final String SM_NAME_COLUMN = "name";
    static final String SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN = "tbl_name";
    static final String SM_ROOTPAGE_COLUMN = "rootpage";
    static final String SM_SQL_COLUMN = "sql";
    static final String SM_TYPE_TABLE = "table";
    static final String SM_TYPE_INDEX = "index";

    static final String PRAGMA_STATEMENT = "PRAGMA ";
    static final String PRAGMA_DATABASELIST = "database_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_USERVERSION = "user_version";
    static final String PRAGMA_ENCODING = "encoding";
    static final String PRAGMA_FOREIGNKEYLIST = "foreign_key_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXINFO = "index_info";
    static final String PRAGMA_INDEXLIST = "index_list";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO = "table_info";

    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_SEQ_COL = "seq";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL = "file";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_CID_COL = "cid";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl = "name";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL = "type";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NOTNULL_COL = "notnull";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL = "dflt_value";
    static final String PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL = "pk";





    static final String CSU_TAG = "SQLITE_CSU";

    private CommonSQLiteUtilities() {}

    /**
     * Write Database information to the log;
     * Information wrttien is:
     * the database path, (will/should show connected databases)
     * the version number (note! user version i.e. version coded in DBHelper),
     * the tables in the database (includes android_metadata but not sqlite_master),
     * the columns of the tables
     * @param db    The SQLite database to be interrogated
     */
    public static void logDatabaseInfo(SQLiteDatabase db) {

        // Issue PRAGMA database_list commnand
        Cursor dblcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_DATABASELIST,null);
        // Write databases to the log
        while (dblcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"DatabaseList Row " + Integer.toString(dblcsr.getPosition() + 1) +
                    " Name=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_NAME_COL)) +
                    " File=" + dblcsr.getString(dblcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_DBLIST_FILE_COL))
            );
        }
        dblcsr.close();
        // Issue PRAGMA user_version to get the version and write to the log
        //Note! to set user_version use execSQL not rawQuery
        Cursor uvcsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_USERVERSION,null);
        while (uvcsr.moveToNext()) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Database Version = " +
                    Integer.toString(uvcsr.getInt(uvcsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_USERVERSION))));
        }
        uvcsr.close();
        // Select all table entry rows from sqlite_master
        Cursor tlcsr = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " +
                        SQLITE_MASTER + " WHERE " +
                        SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "='" + SM_TYPE_TABLE + "'"
                ,null);
        // For each table write table information to the log
        // (inner loop gets column info per table)
        while (tlcsr.moveToNext()) {
            String current_table = tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN));
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                    "Table Name = " + current_table +
                            " Created Using = " + tlcsr.getString(tlcsr.getColumnIndex(SM_SQL_COLUMN)),
                    null
            );
            // Issue PRAGMA tabel_info for the current table
            Cursor ticsr = db.rawQuery(PRAGMA_STATEMENT + PRAGMA_TABLEINFO +
                            "(" + current_table + ")",
                    null
            );
            // Write column info (see headings below) to the log
            while (ticsr.moveToNext()) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table = " +
                                current_table +
                                " ColumnName = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_NAME_COl)) +
                                " ColumnType = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_TYPE_COL)) +
                                " Default Value = " +
                                ticsr.getString(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_DEFAULTVALUE_COL)) +
                                " PRIMARY KEY SEQUENCE = " + Integer.toString(
                        ticsr.getInt(ticsr.getColumnIndex(PRAGMA_TABLEINFO_PRIMARYKEY_COL))
                        )
                );
            }
            ticsr.close();
        }
        tlcsr.close();
    }

    /**
     * Generic get all rows from an SQlite table,
     * allowing the existence of the table to be checked and also
     * allowing the ROWID to be added AS a supplied string
     *
     * @param db                    The SQLiteDatabase
     * @param tablename             The name of the table from which the
     *                              returned cursor will be created from;
     *                              Note!
     * @param use_error_checking    Whether ot not to try to detect errors
     *                              currently just table doesn't exist,
     *                              true to turn on, false to turn off
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_ON = true
     *                              ERROR_CHECKING_OFF = false
     * @param forceRowidAs          If length of string passed is 1 or greater
     *                              then a column, as an alias of ROWID, will be
     *                              added to the cursor
     * @return                      the extracted cursor, or in the case of the
     *                              underlying table not existing an empty cursor
     *                              with no columns
     */
    public static Cursor getAllRowsFromTable(SQLiteDatabase db,
                                             String tablename,
                                             boolean use_error_checking,
                                             String forceRowidAs) {
        String[] columns = null;

        // Tablename must be at least 1 character in length
        if (tablename.length() < 1) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                    " is finishing as the provided tablename is less than 1 character in length"
            );
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }

        // If use_error_checking is true then check that the table exists
        // in the sqlite_master table
        if (use_error_checking) {
            Cursor chkcsr = db.query(SQLITE_MASTER,null,
                    SM_TABLE_TYPE_COLUMN + "=? AND "
                            + SM_TABLENAME_COLUMN + "=?",
                    new String[]{SM_TYPE_TABLE,tablename},
                    null,null,null
            );

            // Ooops table is not in the Database so return an empty
            // column-less cursor
            if (chkcsr.getCount() < 1) {
                Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Table " + tablename +
                        " was not located in the SQLite Database Master Table."
                );
                // return empty cursor with no columns
                return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});

            }
            chkcsr.close();
        }

        // If forcing an alias of ROWID then user ROWID AS ???, *
        if(forceRowidAs != null && forceRowidAs.length() > 0) {
            columns = new String[]{"rowid AS " +forceRowidAs,"*"};
        }

        // Finally return the Cursor but trap any exceptions
        try {
            return db.query(tablename, columns, null, null, null, null, null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Exception encountered but trapped when querying table " + tablename +
                    " Message was: \n" + e.getMessage());
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Stacktrace was:");
            e.printStackTrace();
            return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
        }
    }

    /**
     * Create and return a Cursor devoid of any rows and columns
     * Not used, prehaps of very little use.
     * @param db    The Sqlite database in which the cursor is to be created
     * @return      The empty Cursor
     */
    private static Cursor getEmptyColumnLessCursor(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        return new MatrixCursor(new String[]{});
    }

    /**
     * Write column names in the passed Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor to be inspected.
     */
    public static void logCursorColumns(Cursor csr) {
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " invoked. Cursor has the following " +
                        Integer.toString(csr.getColumnCount())+
                        " columns.");
        int position = 0;
        for (String column: csr.getColumnNames()) {
            position++;
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,"Column Name " +
                    Integer.toString(position) +
                    " is "
                    + column
            );
        }
    }

    /**
     * Write the contents of the Cursor to the log
     * @param csr   The Cursor that is to be displayed in the log
     */
    public static void logCursorData(Cursor csr) {
        int columncount = csr.getColumnCount();
        int rowcount = csr.getCount();
        int csrpos = csr.getPosition(); //<<< added 20171016
        Log.d(CSU_TAG,
                new Object(){}.getClass().getEnclosingMethod().getName() +
                        " Cursor has " +
                        Integer.toString(rowcount) +
                        " rows with " +
                        Integer.toString(columncount) + " columns."
        );
        csr.moveToPosition(-1);     //Ensure that all rows are retrieved <<< added 20171016
        while (csr.moveToNext()) {
            String unobtainable = "unobtainable!";
            String logstr = "Information for row " + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition() + 1) + " offset=" + Integer.toString(csr.getPosition());
            for (int i=0; i < columncount;i++) {
                logstr = logstr + "\n\tFor Column " + csr.getColumnName(i);
                switch (csr.getType(i)) {
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_NULL:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is NULL";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_FLOAT:
                        logstr = logstr + "Type is FLOAT";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_INTEGER:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is INTEGER";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_STRING:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is STRING";
                        break;
                    case Cursor.FIELD_TYPE_BLOB:
                        logstr = logstr + " Type is BLOB";
                        break;
                }
                String strval_log = " value as String is ";
                String lngval_log = " value as long is ";
                String dblval_log = " value as double is ";
                String blbval_log = "";
                try {
                    strval_log = strval_log + csr.getString(i);
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + csr.getLong(i);
                    dblval_log = dblval_log +  csr.getDouble(i);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    strval_log = strval_log + unobtainable;
                    lngval_log = lngval_log + unobtainable;
                    dblval_log = dblval_log + unobtainable;
                    try {
                        blbval_log = " value as blob is " +
                                getBytedata(csr.getBlob(i),24);
                    } catch (Exception e2) {
                        e2.printStackTrace();
                    }

                }
                logstr = logstr + strval_log + lngval_log + dblval_log + blbval_log;
            }
            Log.d(CSU_TAG,logstr);
        }
        csr.moveToPosition(csrpos); // restore cursor position <<< added 20171016
    }

    /**
     * Return a hex string of the given byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be converted to a hexadecimal string
     * @param limit     the maximum number of bytes;
     *                  note returned string will be up to twice as long
     * @return          The byte array represented as a hexadecimal string
     */
    private static String getBytedata(byte[] bytes, int limit) {
        if (bytes.length < limit) {
            return convertBytesToHex(bytes);
        } else {
            byte[] subset = new byte[limit];
            System.arraycopy(bytes,0,subset,0,limit);
            return convertBytesToHex(subset);
        }
    }

    // HEX characters as a char array for use by convertBytesToHex
    private final static char[] hexarray = "0123456789ABCDEF".toCharArray();

    /**
     * Return a hexadecimal string representation of the passed byte array
     * @param bytes     The byte array to be represented.
     * @return          The string representing the byte array as hexadecimal
     */
    private static String convertBytesToHex(byte[] bytes) {
        char[] hexstr = new char[bytes.length * 2];
        for (int i=0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
            int h = bytes[i] & 0xFF;
            hexstr[i * 2] = hexarray[h >>> 4];
            hexstr[i * 2 + 1] = hexarray[h & 0xF];
        }
        return new String(hexstr);
    }
}
```

#### activity_catalog.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".CatalogActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_view_pet"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. I tried adding the class CommonSQLiteUtilities.java and adjusted the code as per your version of it:         PetDbHelper mDbHelper = new PetDbHelper(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = mDbHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        displayDatabaseInfo();
        CommonSQLiteUtilities.logDatabaseInfo(mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase()); However, there are still no tables in the shelter.db database :( See the AS Terminal log below: D:\Udacity\ABND projects>sqlite3 shelter.db
SQLite version 3.24.0 2018-06-04 19:24:41
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
sqlite>

Comment: @Soralka when you run does it show 0 rows in Pets database? Did you check the log to see what the output from the logDataBaseInfo was?

Comment: it's really strange, the LOG seems to be mentioning the pets table, but when I saved the shelter.db on my PC and tried to open it via the AS Terminal, again it was empty.. The LOG is too long for a comment, I will add it to my original question. Thank you for your help!

Comment: @Soralka the database exists and also the pets table. The database is located at **`/data/user/0/com.example.android.pets/databases/shelter.db`**. So it's likely that the commands that you are entering via the terminal are at fault. I've never used the Terminal (I use Genymotion and can therefore access databases via device explorer). I'd suggest continuing with coding, knowing that the databases and table do exist.

Comment: @Soralka I followed the guide here [How to Access SQLite Database in Android using ADB Shell?](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/access-sqlite-database/) and all worked fine (I used the `.dump` command).

Comment: 1/3 Thanks for your continuous support! A strange thing happened - I could not access the database from command prompt - this is where it got stuck: 
generic_x86:/ $ cd data/data/com.example.android.pets/databases
/system/bin/sh: cd: /data/data/com.example.android.pets/databases: Permission denied
2|generic_x86:/ $ # cd data/data/com.example.android.pets/databases
2|generic_x86:/ $ sqlite3 shelter.db
SQLite version 3.22.0 2018-01-22 18:45:57
Enter ".help" for usage hints.
sqlite> .tables
Error: unable to open database "shelter.db": unable to open database file

Comment: 2/3 However, after that failed, I tried accessing the database once more via the Android terminal - and now it works:
sqlite> .tables
android_metadata  pets
sqlite> PRAGMA TABLE_INFO(pets);
0|_id|INTEGER|0||1
1|name|TEXT|1||0
2|breed|TEXT|0||0
3|gender|INTEGER|1||0
4|weight|INTEGER|1|0|0
sqlite> .schema
CREATE TABLE android_metadata (locale TEXT);
CREATE TABLE pets (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, name TEXT NOT NULL, breed TEXT, gender INTEGER NOT NULL, weight INTEGER NOT NULL DEFAULT 0);
CREATE TABLE sqlite_sequence(name,seq);
sqlite>

Comment: 3/3 No idea why since the Command prompt exercise seems to have failed (permission denied..). Somewhere along the way, some of the commands in Command prompt must have changed something in AS/device settings.. Maybe it was that I connected the shell to the device? (Whatever that is..) I still don't understand exactly how this got fixed, but it did get fixed and I can continue in my course! Thanks again for your help, I will document these steps for my fellow students if they face a similar issue. Thanks!! :)

Comment: @Soralka my opinion is that it's easier to use log commands to check if the database/tables exist. The shell is a link to the operating system commands (so it's important). At a guess your permission issue was that the equivalent to the shell `/system/bin/sh` was where the permission failed, whilst using the command `shell` works as the command itself allows permission.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the main issue was: I was using an emulator with an API 28. Apparently, anything above API 23 is an issue when trying to access databases.

So I made a new emulator API 23 and now I don't have any issues with the permissions etc.

@MikeT - this seems to have been why I was struggling with getting the permissions.