# How to check whether the value is inserted or not in SQLite?

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

How to check whether the value is inserted or not in Android?

I want to display

```
if inserted==true
   return true;
else
   return false;
```

This is my code:

```
SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
sqLiteDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO user VALUES (1,1,1,'admin','admin','21232f297a57a5a743894a0e4a801fc3','9986058114','8897456588','admin@admin.com','','Active','AD','admin')");
```

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151598/8448886

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check By DataBase : https://stackoverflow.com/a/21151598/8448886

You can also use Log to check data is inserted on or not on your DataBaseHelper class.

```
  public boolean addData(String name , String sku, String upc , String price, String displaySize, int displaySizeYes, String status){
    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
    contentValues.put(Constants.NAME, name );
    contentValues.put(Constants.SKU, sku );
    contentValues.put(Constants.UPC, upc );
    contentValues.put(Constants.PRICE, price );
    contentValues.put(Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE, displaySize );
    contentValues.put(Constants.DISPLAY_SIZE_YES, displaySizeYes );
    contentValues.put(Constants.STATUS, status );

    long result = db.insert(Constants.TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
    Log.e(TAG,""+upc+"  Inserted");

    if(result == -1) {
        return false;
    }else{
      //  Log.e(TAG,"value inserted");
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not showing accepted , left side of the answer click on correct symbol @Aravind

Comment: Accept means check on correct symbol at starting of my answer below of voting up and down.

Comment: Yes i did that. Sorry I didn't noticed it

Comment: no issue , Now you have enough reputation to vote up too @Aravind

Answer (score 0):

```
public int numberOfRowsRecord() {
    db =  this.getReadableDatabase();
    return (int) DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(db, RECORD_TABLE_NAME);
}
```

> Add this code in your helper class

this function return either number of **row** affected by this...

so you can check you value is **inserted** or not...